# Tell Terraform not to destroy and create when updating a null_resource

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I have a `null_resource` that is used to install/uninstall Kubernetes YAML manifests, and looks as follows:

```
resource "null_resource" "manifest_provisioner" {
  count = var.enabled ? 1 : 0

  triggers = {
    manifest_file = <actual_content_of_the_yaml_manifest>
  }

  # Create-time provisioner
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "kubectl apply -f -<<EOF\n${self.triggers.manifest_file}\nEOF"
  }

  # Destroy-time provisioner
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when = destroy
    command = "kubectl delete -f -<<EOF\n${self.triggers.manifest_file}\nEOF"
  }
}
```

When adding a new manifest, or asking to delete it, the resource works as expected.

However, whenever I want to update an existing manifest, Terraform would first destroy and then create the resource, which means that an update would always incur a full deletion of Kubernetes objects which is problematic.

How can I instruct this resource to only run the create-time provisioner when updating an existing resource?

Comment: Your `kubectl apply` command should already be idempotent so why not just let Terraform run it on every `terraform apply` command? You could do that by setting the trigger to use `uuid()` or `timestamp()` so it changes on every apply. Alternatively you might be interested in [this alternate Kubernetes provider](https://github.com/banzaicloud/terraform-provider-k8s) that allows you to use raw manifest files rather than rewriting them in HCL if that's what you're trying to avoid but still want Terraform to be used for other things.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment by @ydaetskcoR, you can use `uuid()` or `timestamp()` to always apply the changes.

If the reason for not opting the [terraform kubernetes provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs) is not the availability for support of the resource that you're deploying, you can use [kubectl provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gavinbunney/kubectl/latest/docs/resources/kubectl_manifest#example-usage), which should easily help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Add `when = create` to your `kubectl apply..` provisioner